# Бота для Telegram на Heroku работает не более минуты

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, telegram

Есть бот. Размещен на Heroku. Запускается из Procfile вот так:

```
web: python UselessBot.py
```

Проблема в том,что он падает через 60 секунд с вот таким логом

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

и не перезапускается. Как пофиксить? Понимаю, что ему нужен какой-то порт... но я не понимаю, откуда он берется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упс, нашел, где косяк. Изменил Procfile следующим образом:

```
bot: python UselessBot.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно не так, это не исправит проблему. Дело в том что Хероку не предназначен для размещения ботов как таковых. У тебя Хероку ищет якобы существующее  веб-приложение и соответственно его порт, после ненахождения - падает. Лучше скопипасть питоновское приложение, которое Хероку дает для примера и прикрути бота к нему как worker. Ну или создавай django  или flask приложение а не просто питоновский скрипт.

Comment: у меня таким макаром уже стабильно работают 2 бота. Я не просто так САМ ответи на свой вопрос

Comment: В последнем предложении понял сам-то что написал? И да, если они так работают, то ты явно понимаешь в хероку что то не до конца(